# making 4 out of 1 file with awk

Tags: bash, awk

i have large list - text file with 1 column of numbers (length=14).
Numbers have 4 difrent prefixes 00001-00004.
how do i split 1 list to 4 diffrend files.
1 file shoud contain list of numbers with one prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Use that `awk` command:

```
awk '/^00001/{print >"file1"} \
     /^00002/{print >"file2"} \
     /^00003/{print >"file3"} \
     /^00004/{print >"file4"}' inputfile
```

It check which prefix the line has and prints the whole line to `file1` to `file4`. `inputfile` is the file with the large list.

Answer (score 1):

Using (G)awk and match

```
awk 'match($0,/^0000([1-4])/,a){print > "file"a[1]}' file
```

Posix awk

```
awk '/0000[1-4]/{print > "file"substr($0,5,1)}' file
```

or if they all have prefixes just

```
awk '{print > "file"substr($0,5,1)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use just `bash`

```
while IFS= read -r num
do
  echo "$num" >> "file${num:4:1}"
done < number_list.file
```